# How to display normalized categories in Altair stacked bar chart tooltip

Tags: altair

I'm creating a stacked bar chart using the count of a categorical field in a dataframes column.

```
 chart = alt.Chart(df2).mark_bar().encode(
            x="take__take:O",
            y=alt.Y('count(name)', stack="normalize", axis=alt.Axis(title="Percent", format="%")),
            color=alt.Color('name', sort=alt.EncodingSortField('value', order='descending')),
            order=alt.Order(
                'value',
                sort="ascending"
            ),
            tooltip=[
                alt.Tooltip('count(name)', title="Total Students")
            ]
        )
```

How would I go about getting the normalized count in the tooltip?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Up until now your chart uses encoding shorthands to compute various aggregates; for more complicated operations (like displaying normalized values in tooltips) you will need to use [transforms](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/index.html) directly.

Here is an example of displaying per-group percentages in a tooltip, using a chart similar to what you showed above:

```python
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], size=100),
    'value': np.random.randint(0, 20, 100),
    'take__take': np.random.randint(0, 5, 100)
})

alt.Chart(df2).transform_aggregate(
    count='count()',
    groupby=['name', 'take__take']
).transform_joinaggregate(
    total='sum(count)',
    groupby=['take__take']  
).transform_calculate(
    frac=alt.datum.count / alt.datum.total
).mark_bar().encode(
    x="take__take:O",
    y=alt.Y('count:Q', stack="normalize", axis=alt.Axis(title="Percent", format="%")),
    color='name:N',
    tooltip=[
        alt.Tooltip('count:Q', title="Total Students"),
        alt.Tooltip('frac:Q', title="Percentage of Students", format='.0%')
    ]
)
```

[image]